# error 500.19 IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, iis

tengo una alicacion desarrollada en .net mvc 5 con framework 4.6.1, estoy realizando un servidor local IIS 7.5 de windows 7 para que funcione en una red local, ya lo configure y cuando agrego mis archivos para que se despliegue mi aplicacion en .net me genera error 500.19, pero cuando agrego archivos html no tengo problemas en que se muestren:

> "Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   No se puede obtener acceso a la página solicitada porque los datos de configuración relacionados de la página no son válidos."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="HOLA" connectionString="Server=sql20;Database=082018;Uid=sa;Pwd=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
    <add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="intranet" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="CNH.Licitaciones.Web" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <add name="SiteMapLic" type="Samples.AspNet.SimpleTextSiteMapProvider,Samples.AspNet" siteMapFile="Lic.siteMap" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: FA9770B2-2504-4BE7-B52A-7A786D6D31A7-->
```

Comment: Podrias compartir tu Web.config ?¿ por lo que dice es un error de configuración, me quiero imaginar que de forma local en el equipo donde estas desarrollando funciona correctamente.

Comment: @M.Gress arriba coloque el coidgo del webconfig

Comment: ¿Has configurado el Pool de tu aplicación en IIS para que funcione con el framework 4.6.1?

Comment: @M.Gress si, el IIS 7.5 solo tiene hasta la version 4.0.30319 del Framework, no se si ahi este el problema

Comment: Podrias probar compilando tu aplicación con un versión menor del framework y ver si corre de esa forma.

Comment: @M.Gress me genera errores si lo compilo con otra version del framework, se puede instalar otra version de IIS mi pc?

Answer (score 2):

En tu Application Pool, dentro de IIS, verifica que la opción "Managed Pipeline Mode" (o su equivalente en español), esté configurado como "Integrated", mas o menos como se ve en la imagen.

[image: Ejemplo]

De igual manera, veo que tu archivo de configuración esta en el escritorio. Intenta mover tu desarrollo a la carpeta c:\inetpub\wwwroot, ya que ésta cuenta con los permisos necesarios.

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado lo mismo y he encontrado la solución, por si a alguien le sirve.

Al igual que a ti, me aparecía '`ruta de archivo ?/C:/...`'.

Se debe a que el archivo `applicationhost.config` dentro de `.vs/Nombre/config` en la propiedad `<virtualDirectory>` contiene una ruta que en mi máquina no existía.