# Error HTTP 500.19 IIS 10.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Hola compañeros espero me puedan apoyar, realice una aplicacion en net core 6, estoy tratando de desplegarla, pero me sale el error `500.19`, ya realice los pasos de la respuesta [error 500.19 IIS 7.5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190826/error-500-19-iis-7-5?rq=1) , tambien cree un usuario llamado `IIS_IUSRS` y le di todos los permisos en la carpeta, tengo instalados los sdk´s 6 y 7 como los runtime. Pero por mas que eh intentado no logro resolverlo, en el error sale que puede ser el `web.config` pero no tengo idea de que sea el error. Espero me puedan apoyar.

Este es mi web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
   </handlers>
   <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SistemaAgente2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Este es el error que me arroja, tambien ya busque el código del error que me arroja `0x8007000d`, pero no logro corregirlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa el EventViewer, ¿qué error marca?

Comment: Dentro del eventViewer, donde me voy ? nunca eh buscado un error ahi dentro.

Comment: El tema es amplio, revisa algunos videos para que tengas una idea general: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=eventviewer+windows+server+como+usarlo En breve: inicio -> tipeas "Event Viewer", En esa app, en la izquierda: Windows Logs -> Application. Y ver lo que hay ahí.